# Why does Symfony's @templating service provide different classes in dev and prod?

Tags: symfony, twig

I had a service which was working fine in dev.  It looked a bit like this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;

public function __construct(TwigEngine $twig)
{
    $this->twig = $twig;
}

// service methods here
```

I instantiate it in `services.yml` by passing it `@templating`.

In dev, all worked well, but in our staging environment (which uses Symfony's `prod` environment), I saw a 500 error which said that the argument

```
must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine
```

but instead...

```
instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\DelegatingEngine given.
```

I resolved this by following the suggestion in [this semi-related bug report](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4742) and type-hinting on `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface` instead.

However, I'd like to know why this happens - why is a `TwigEngine` instance passed in `dev` (and `test`), but a `DelegatingEngine` in `prod`?

The relevant lines from my `config.yml` look like this:

```
framework:
    templating: { engines: ['twig'] }
```

(I tried changing this to `engines: 'twig'` - i.e. using a string rather than an array - but this didn't affect anything.)

Anyone know why the behaviour differs across environments?

Comment: You will find hints here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating/introduction.html#using-multiple-engines

Comment: Hi @COil.  Unfortunately, I'm not actually using multiple engines (which is what the `DelegatingEngine` helps with and what that article you linked to talks about).  See my notes about `config.yml` in the original post.  Thanks for responding, though!

Comment: Twig templates are cached in the production environment while they are always rerendered in the development environment. I assume it has something to do with that - different classes are used.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony allows having different engines per controller action via `@Template(engine='foo')` ([doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html)).

**Old answer:**

> For development environment you wan't to have some **extra info**
>   about template rendering process (timing, memory consumption, number
>   of blocks rendered, etc.). This info can be accessed via profiler or
>   dev toolbar in default configuration.
>
> However this is usually wasteful for production environment where you
>   want **performance**.
>
> Thus to match different needs framework has different configuration
>   for prod/dev environment.

This could be implemented without DelegatingEngine just fine. See [TimedPhpEngine](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/TimedPhpEngine.php).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but are you sure that it's this extra info that the `DelegatingEngine` provides?  That engine is more to do with managing [multiple possible template engines](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating/introduction.html#using-multiple-engines) rather than providing debug information.  I'd expect the kind of debugging information you mention to simply be be conditionally exposed by the normal templating engine.

Comment: I checked the code - debug info has nothing to do with DelegatingEngine. Updated answer.

Comment: I didn't know that this could be specified using controller annotations, thanks for the tip!  Unfortunately, this doesn't explain the dev/prod discrepancy.

Comment: When you need to add functionality existing class, you can use either inheritance or composition. I.e. pass `TwigEngine` or `PhpEngine` into `ProfilingEngine`. This way you get flexibility to wrap any engine at price, that `instanceof TwigEngine` check fails. To deal with this check `EngineInterface` is used.

Comment: Just add breakpoint in your setter and see what kind of engine you are getting passed in each env.